# HTML button calling Event listener not working HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have made a list of items with JSON and JS and I need to be able to delete them.

```
function deleteList(){
  document.querySelector('#delete').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('#exerciseList').innerHTML = '';
  });
}
```

Here is my HTML button:

```
<button onclick="deleteList()" id="delete">Clear List</button>
<section id="exerciseList"></section>
```

are these just not connected right?

Answer (score 0):

You either add an event listener or the `onclick` attribute, so

```js
function deleteList() {
  document.querySelector("#exerciseList").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deleteList()" id="delete">Clear List</button>
<section id="exerciseList">list</section>
```

or, recommended:

```js
document.querySelector("#delete").addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.querySelector("#exerciseList").innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<button id="delete">Clear List</button>
<section id="exerciseList">list</section>
```

Comment: Happy to hear @ZachNChelseaBlaszczyk, if it helped you consider accepting the answer to mark this as solved. Thank you!